# Allow only alphanumeric, dash, underscore, and period in string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a file upload page script (Javascript).  The user selects a file from their machine.

I need to strip out anything from the string containing the file name that is not:

- A letter
- A number
- a dash
- an underscore
- A period

I have been trying to use the Javascript replace function to remove the unnecessary characters. I am able to remove all the non-alphanumeric parts using:

```
rawFilename = data.files[0].name;  
safeFilename = rawFilename.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

That leaves in the letter, numbers, and underscore, but I need to also allow dash and periods.  I'm not sure what the correct regex to select the dash and periods as well would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty simple using a negative [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w.-]+/g, "");
```

The only gotcha is that the `-` needs to be either first or last in the list, because it can be interpreted as the range operator.

Comment: Or the dash could just be escaped too

Comment: @Gary As in `[^\w\.\-]`

Comment: @1.21gigawatts That would be fine, but if the dash is last in a character class, there's no real need to escape it for it to be treated literally.  I was just pointing out that it didn't _have_ to be first/last in this case if it were escaped instead.  I guess I should've said "instead" in place of "too".

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer by Lucas

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w\.\-]/g, "");
```

Dashes and periods can be any location.